# Performance for safely handling out of range exceptions?

Tags: swift

I [have an extension](http://www.vadimbulavin.com/handling-out-of-bounds-exception/) of `Collection` that allows for safe access to elements without checking each time. This is what my extension looks like:

```
extension Collection {

    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
        indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

The time complexity of `indices.contains(index)` is `O(n)` which is a tough trade off. Is there a way to do this with `O(1)`?

Comment: This is O(1) any time `.contains` is O(1). For example, Array.Indices is a Range, and `Range.contains` is O(1): https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift#L185-L186. In principle, this can't be done faster than contains. But what you could do is create a protocol SafeCollection, make this the default implementation, and then provide custom implementations for collections that require it.

Comment: (But in my experience, after pushing for this in the stdlib many years ago and being talked out of it, you should rethink whether you even want this. You should strongly avoid using an index on a collection that you didn't just retrieve from that collection. Lots of things invalidate indexes, so they are not long-lived things, and can't be computed. You should think of Indexes as short-lived pointers. I found by experience that most places where this would possibly make sense, I should have been using other interfaces like iteration anyway.)

Comment: You hit it right on the mark, the complexity is based on whose implementing the `Collection` and `indices.contains` will naturally work to the best it can. Pls add the answer and I will mark it as the solution because this is the right answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is O(1) any time `.contains` is O(1). For example, Array.Indices is a Range, and [`Range.contains` is O(1)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift#L185-L186). In principle, this can't be done faster than `contains`. But what you could do is create a protocol SafeCollection, make this the default implementation, and then provide custom implementations for collections that require it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe checking against only the `firstIndex` and the `lastIndex` would be enough for indexes in *various* situations:

```
subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {
    index >= startIndex && index <= endIndex ? self[index] : nil
}
```

But `contains` function itself uses the `O(1)` in some situations (like when index is from an Array.Indices) as @rob Described in his answer.

Comment: The key point here is that you need to add additional `where` restrictions on the extension. For example, `where Index: Comparable`. You also need to check for `< endIndex` (not <=). The end index is not part of the collection.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `Collection.Index` is *required* to be `Comparable`. On the other hand, comparing a “valid“ index with an “invalid index” might be undefined behavior, so I wonder if all this is of any use for anything but (integer-indexed) arrays or array slices.

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I had thought they just had to be Equatable for the base protocol, but yeah, it does require Comparable.